# How to send Vala ArrayList through D-Bus?

Tags: glib, dbus, vala, gdbus, libgee

Trying to send data from server to client and getting this error:

```
error: GVariant serialization of type `Gee.ArrayList' is not supported
public abstract ArrayList<EventData?> get_event_list () throws IOError;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a plain array. A good resource for showing D-Bus types mapped to Vala types is the [Type Table in Vala D-Bus Examples](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/DBusServerSample#Type_Table).

For `EventData` you should consider a Variant, struct or `ObjectPath`.